# NullReferenceException for Public class member

Tags: c#

The following code throws "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in..." when the GetDepAirport() method is called.

```
    public WYPT GetDepAirport()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Retrieving Airport in GetDepApt()");
        Console.WriteLine("Departure Airport is {0}", Dep.Ident);
        return Dep;
    }

    public void SetDepAirport(String ident)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Setting Airport with ident {0}, ident");
        Dep = FetchDBAirport(ident);
        Console.WriteLine("WYPT Dep is set to {0}", Dep.Ident);
    }
```

The output is:

```
Setting Airport with ident KABQ
WYPT Dep is set to KABQ
Retrieving Airport in GetDepApt()
```

Followed by a slough of exceptions.  I cannot figure out why **Dep** (declared public) is getting returned as *null* when called from the GetDepAirport() method.  Both methods are being called from within a separate method in the same class.

Declaration is at the top of the class:

```
class FlightPlan
{
   //Init Pg.1 data
    public WYPT Dep, Dest, Altn;
```

The call to set is from a different class:

```
FlightPlan FPlan = new FlightPlan(); 
FPlan.SetDepAirport(Dep);
```

The call to Get comes later:

```
    public void GetFPlan()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
        {
            Waypoint[i] = new WYPT();
        }
        Waypoint[0] = GetDepAirport();
        Waypoint[1] = DISCON;
```

FetchDBAirport method in same FlightPlan class

```
private WYPT FetchDBAirport(String airport)
    {
        WYPT Airport = new WYPT();

        String databasepath = "C:\\Users\\Family\\documents\\visual studio 2012\\Projects\\FMST\\FMST\\Database\\NavData.mdf";
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" + databasepath + ";Integrated Security=True");
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = myConnection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Airports WHERE Ident='" + airport + "';";
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            rdr.Read();

            Airport.Ident = (String)rdr.GetValue(0);
            Airport.Lat = (decimal)rdr.GetValue(2);
            Airport.Lon = (decimal)rdr.GetValue(3);
            Airport.Elev = (decimal)rdr.GetValue(4);

            myConnection.Close();
            return Airport;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString() + "Happy Face");
            String ErrorMsg = "NOT FOUND";
            Airport.Ident = ErrorMsg;
            return Airport;
        }
```

Comment: Your not showing us where or how you declared it.

Comment: Dep is never being set in the provided code.  We need more info.

Comment: Maybe it is the `FetchDPAirport(ident);` that is returning null.

Comment: Looks like Dep is being set to null somewhere between your call to SetDepAirport and the call to GetDepAirport in the calling method. We need to see the method that the calls are made from.

Comment: The FetchDBAirport is returning the correct data and its being Set before I call the Get as far as I can tell. Reference the Output section above.   I added the declaration above.

Comment: can you show the `FetchDBAirport` method?

Comment: I may have found my problem, but don't know how to rectify.  I am actually calling the Set from another class and define it as such. Added above.  The FetchDBAirport method works or else it wouldn't return the Ident.  It also returns other data not shown here.

Comment: I thought you said 'both methods are being called from within a separate method in the same class'. Can you include all of the relevant code? Something must be happening between the Set and Get calls.

Comment: Yikes!  Its a lot of code.  I'll try.

Comment: @NigelWhatling. I was wrong. Sry. Its been a long day

Comment: @DaveS. Can you set a watch on Dep and step through the code yourself?  It's got to be losing it's value at some point.

Comment: @NigelWhatling. Yes!  Ill do that and see.  (like I said...long day)

Comment: I discovered the problem has to do with scope.  Once the method that calls the SetDepAirport() method ends in the other class, the Dep variable goes back to null.

Comment: Changed the variable to 'public static' and all is well.  Talk about 8 hours wasted trying to get it to work. Thanks everyone for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

The only part of the code that could return a NullReferenceException in GetDepAirport is `Dep.Ident`. Either `Dep` or `Ident` could be null. If you add a null check for both of those then the method will run fine.

As for why either of those is null, it could be because:

- You have not called `SetDepAirport` before calling `GetDepAirport`
- `FetchDBAirport` is either returning null, or returning a `Dep` instance where `Ident` is null.
- The code that called GetDepAirport is altering the value of Dep somewhere else
- Dep is not storing the value correctly - so perhaps a problem in the property definition

Comment: I am setting the airport first and have used Console.WriteLine's to verify the data is set from the database (Fetch...).  I am investigating your last two bullets as im seriously scratching my head on this one.

Comment: I think the four bullets listed above are a logically complete set of causes - it must be one of them!

Comment: I discovered the problem has to do with scope.  Once the method that calls the SetDepAirport() method ends, the Dep variable goes back to null.

Comment: Problem was simpler than that.  I changed the Dep variable to static and all is well.  Works like a champ now.

Comment: I'm glad it works, but just to point out, usually you should avoid storing state statically like that because that one field will be shared between all instances of the class it is in. If one instance of the class changes the value, then it will apply to all other instances of the class too. It should work fine as an instance (non-static) field.